# Calculate the amount of time between two dates and return a true/false if it's been over/under X amount of years

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I'd like to create a query that would take a field (datetime) and compare it to the current time (using `GETDATE()`). If it's been 10 years since that field and today, return true, else false.

I tried using the `DATEDIFF()` function, but it doesn't seem to take into account months/days. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Show sample data and desired results. `DATEDIFF` relies on _date boundaries_, not passage of time. What do you expect the result to be for Jan 1st, 2010? How about December 31st, 2010? How about October 12th, 13th, or 14th, 2010? Do you want to count 365 days as a year? What about leap years? Please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't really have "true" and "false".  I would use `1` and `0`:

```
select (case when field < dateadd(year, -10, getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) as flag_10yr
```

Note that this does direct comparisons of the dates rather than `datediff()`.  That function counts the number of boundaries between two years, which is not the same thing -- 2019-12-31 and 2020-01-01 are "1 year apart" according to this function.

Answer (score 1):

Datediff should do the job if the datepart parameter is set to 'year'.

```
declare @field      datetime='2001-01-01';

select case when datediff(year, @field, getdate())>=10 then 'True' else 'False' end;
```

Output

```
True
```

[EDIT] Alternately, if you like the actual number of 365 day periods between a datetime and GETDATE, you could use the datepart 'day' and divide by 365.

Query

```
select case when datediff(day, @field, getdate())/365>=10 then 'True' else 'False' end
```

Output

```
True
```

Comment: Datediff is not an accurate suggestion since it counts boundaries. Datediff (in years) between Jan 1 2020 and Dec 31 2019 is still 1 because it crosses a year boundary - while most people would say that is just wrong. In addition, the use of a function on a column will prevent the optimizer from considering any useful indexes that contain that column (i.e., the filter will not be sargable) when used as a filter. Gordon's approach is preferred for these reasons.